# Long Press Material Design Button Allows Pasting into Button Label

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

**Background**

I have a standard Material Design button, as per below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/medium_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/medium_margin"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="I am a Button"
    style="@style/PrimaryColoredButton" />
```

The style applied to it is as follows

```
<style name="PrimaryColoredButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:capitalize">sentences</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/primary_button_background</item>
</style>
```

**The Problem**

When the button is long pressed, the system paste button appears and allows the user to paste content into the Button's label.

[image: Material Button showing Paste option]

Then after pasting:

[image]

I cannot see a way to stop this from an XML perspective, but it feels like this shouldn't be possible at all.

Interestingly it only happens when the long press is not on the text but the background itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior is not exclusive to `AppCompatButton`s, it seems. It stems from the fact that `Button` is a subclass of `TextView`, and what's actually triggering that behavior in your case is the `capitalize` attribute in your custom style. When this is set <s>to anything other than `none`</s>, it causes `TextView`'s internal `Editor` to become active and respond to long clicks.

In fact, it appears that any attribute setting that causes the `Button` to have an input type other than the default will cause this. These attributes include - but are not limited to - `capitalize`, `digits`, `autoText`, and, obviously, any `inputType` other than `none`. The `textIsSelectable` attribute will cause a little havoc, too, in that the `Button` will act like an un-editable `EditText`. The cursor and selection handle(s) will appear, along with the editing CAB when appropriate, but no input method, and the `Button` becomes un-clickable.

These are clearly not attributes you would normally be setting on a `Button`, but this definitely seems like a bug to me, since `Button` probably shouldn't, in any way, allow itself to become editable. Indeed, in certain states, pasting text, then shifting focus or clicking causes the `Editor` to crash. If this is unintended behavior (the pasting, not the crashing), it's been wrongly implemented for some time, as far as I can tell.

To remedy this, you should remove the `capitalize` attribute from your style, and just handle that yourself when you set the text on the `Button`. Alternatively, if you don't need to respond to long clicks on your `Button`s, you could set the `longClickable` attribute in your style to `false`.

Unfortunately, simply setting the (deprecated) `editable` attribute to `false` doesn't seem to be a fix, if combined with any of the other above-mentioned, problematic attributes.

Comment: I literally just go to the same conclusion! I have the line `<item name="android:capitalize">sentences</item>` in my style and it behaves exactly as you describe.

Comment: Ah, cool. Glad we confirmed each other's findings! I've been trying to write this up for an hour, but I've been stuck with a user on another question. This certainly seems a bug. Maybe we should tell somebody?

Comment: I shall file a bug and then link you if you want to help collaborate the findings?

Comment: Sure thing. I didn't get a chance to dig through `TextView`'s source as thoroughly as I'd like (that class is big), but I'm pretty sure my cursory diagnosis is correct.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213406&thanks=213406&ts=1466154875 - Bug filed here please feel free to contribute more info - thanks again!

Comment: Could a work around be to use TextUtils to alter a standard String. Can't see from an initial look through if it would help. Thinking about Sentence casing.

Comment: I'm not sure if anything in `TextUtils` in particular would help. It'd be easy enough to split a `String` on the necessary punctuation, capitalize each first letter, then join the results. There are probably faster ways, or easier ways. Maybe Apache's `StringUtils` has something.